# How to add Url to Pagination using Ajax with Jquery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

This is the first time that I have make pagination without page refresh by using Ajax with Jquery, PHP and Mysql. [Testpage](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/testsite1/public/index.php)

Is it possible add url like in php? **1=>** `/index.php?page=1` **2=>**`/index.php?page=2` Now i have only index.php.

An example of what I would like to achieve  (https://www.komputronik.pl/producer/51/amd.html?showProducts=1&p=3&showBuyActiveOnly=0)

---

**UPDATE 1**  Added `history.pushStat` now show `public/1` `public/2`... 
But when I go to the product detail (`show.php?id=96`), I can not go back.

show.php `<a class="goback" href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">&laquo; Go back </a>`

```
  $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){
       //e.preventDefault();
       var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
       load_data(page);  
       history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('id'));
       historyedited = true;
  });
```

**1. Ajax (index.php)**

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      load_data();  
      function load_data(page)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"pagination2.php",  
                method:"GET",  
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#page').html(data);
                     //alert('Successfully called');
                }, 
              //error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);} 
           })  
      }  
     //load_data(1);

      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");  
           load_data(page);  
      });  


 });  
 </script>
```

**2. Links(pagination2.php)**

```
if($page_nb > 1) {
    //echo "<a href='index_all.php?page=".$prev_page."'>Back</a>";
    echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$prev_page."'>Back</span>";

}

if ( $products_count > $check ) {

    for ( $i = max( 1, $page_nb - 5 ); $i <= min( $page_nb + 5, $limit ); $i++ ) {
        if ( $current_page == $i ) {
            echo "<span class=\"selected\">{$i}</span>";
        } else {
            //echo "<a href=\"{$url}?page=" . $i . "\">{$i}</a>";
            echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>"; 
        }
      }
    }   



if ($products_count > $check) { 

$next_page = $page_nb + 1;  
    //echo "<a href='index_all.php?page=".$next_page."'>Next</a>";
    echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$next_page."'>Next</span>";

}
```

Comment: You can manipulate the address bar content via the HTML5 History API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API But this on its will not make it so that when `/index.php?page=2` gets bookmarked or send to someone else, it will automatically show page 2 of the posts again the next time it is called, if you don’t have that implemented already, so you might have to make some adjustments on the server side as well in that case.

Comment: I thought it would be easy :) Adding some code:). Do you have any tutorials or example?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** -> [testpage](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/testsite1/public/page=2)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let url_string = window.location.href;
    let url_parts = url_string.split('/');
    let piece = url_parts[url_parts.length - 1]; 
    let page;
    if (piece.substring(0, 5) === 'page=') {
        page = parseInt(piece.substr(5));
    } else { 
        page = 1;
    }
    load_data(page);

    function load_data(page) {
        $('#load_data').html('<div id="status" style="" ></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: "pagination2.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {page: page},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#load_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let page = $(this).attr("id");
        load_data(page);
        //Now push PAGE to URL
        window.history.pushState({page}, `Selected: ${page}`, `${'page=' + page}`)
        return event.preventDefault();
    });
```